# How to spy on function from specific button click using sinon?

Tags: reactjs, sinon, simulate

I'm making test for my first react app and I have two problems that I'm stuck on. Problem one when I look for a button to simulate click on I get button with id='callA' and not get button with a different id. My second problem is I'm trying to use sinon to spy on A() that button with id="callA" calls.

my react App

```
class ReactPage extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
      super(props)
      this.B = this.B.bind(this)
      this.C = this.C.bind(this)
  }

  //other functions

  A = () => {
    //stuff that I don't want to run on button click
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <button id="callA" type="submit" onClick={this.A}>Submit</button>
      <button id="callB" type="submit" onClick={(e) => this.B(e.target.value)} value={7}>Call B</button>
      <button id="callC" type="submit" onClick={(e) => this.C(e.target.value)} value={1}>Call C</button>
      <button id="callD" type="submit" onClick={(e) => this.D(e.target.value)} value={2}>Call D</button>
    );
  }
}
```

this is my attempt to make a test for button that calls A()

```
import {shallow, mount, configure} from 'enzyme';
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';
import sinon from 'sinon';
import ReactPage from './App';

configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });

it('submit button call A()', () => {
  const spy = sinon.spy(ReactPage.prototype, "A");
  const rendered = shallow(<ReactPage />);
  rendered.find("#callA").simulate('click');
  expect(spy.calledOnce).toEqual(true);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `jest` to spy on your instance of `ReactPage`.

```
it('submit button call A()', () => {
  const rendered = shallow(<ReactPage />);
  const spyOn = jest.spy(rendered.instance(), "A");
  rendered.find("#callA").simulate('click');
  expect(spyOn).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

Comment: I tried this. I'm getting a ```TypeError: _jest2.default.spyOn is not a function error.```

Comment: I thought I read once the the ```const spy = jest.spyOn(rendered.instance(), "A");``` has to come before the ```const rendered = shallow(<ReactPage />);```. I tried this but changed the ```rendered.instance()``` to ```ReactPage.prototype``` got the same error as when i used you code.

Comment: Sorry, instead use `jest.spy()` not spyOn. For spying, you need to spy on the instance which is why it comes after the `shallow` render.

Comment: just tried with jest.spy() and got the same error. is it possible that I need to run my test differently to use jest? Currently my npm test runs ```"test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom"``` I noticed that the jest api website says to make test to ```"test": "jest"```. Would that have an effect on using ```jest.spy()```?

Comment: It might do, I just run mine with `jest` as suggested by jest docs.

Comment: I tried changing test to be ```"test":"jest"``` and got ```cannot find module 'sourse-map' from 'sourse-map-support.js'``` this error

Comment: It seems i have something really screwy to my react application when I installed jest. thanks for the help though